# Not Able To Understand Go Context Example

Tags: go, documentation

I am unable to understand the example from Context package go library.
package main

```
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    gen := func(ctx context.Context) <-chan int {
        dst := make(chan int)
        n := 1
        go func() {
            for {
                select {
                case <-ctx.Done():
                    return // returning not to leak the goroutine
                case dst <- n:

                    n++
                }
            }
        }()
        return dst
    }

    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel() // cancel when we are finished consuming integers

    for n := range gen(ctx) {
        fmt.Println(n)
        if n == 5 {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone break the example for me?

I tried adding logs to the program but unable to understand. The gen function is called one time but how it is returning 5 channels

Answer (score 0):

`gen` returns only **one** channel. The `for range` statement can be used with a channel to iterate over its received messages. So, in the context example, `n` is the value received through the `dst` channel that `gen` created and returned.

For more info read: [For statements with range clause](https://go.dev/ref/spec#For_range).